# VIM - Convert normal-mode function to command-mode function

Tags: regex, vim, grep, vi

Good day,

I have a simple function I have mapped to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> which I use in normal-mode to search for all instances in a project of a word or variable:

```
" Find all occurences in files
map <C-l> :execute " grep -srnw --binary-files=without-match --exclude=*~ --exclude-dir=.svn  . -e " . expand("<cword>") . " " <bar> cwindow<CR>
```

I am trying to make a command-mode function out of this so I could do something like:

```
:mySearchFunction wordToFind
```

This way, I effectively get a short and simple "Find in All Files" function so I don't have to type the lengthy `grep` function above all the time. I have tried modifying the code after the `. -e " .expand...` piece of the function, but I am not familiar with writing VI/VIM functions. I am familiar with C and BASH scripting, but I cannot get this function working as expected.

May I have some assistance with making a command-mode function from this mapping of mine?

Thank you.

---

Edit: Posting modified version of the answer from @Conner. Also excludes the CTAGS `tags` file.

```
command! -nargs=1 SearchAll execute " grep -srnw --binary-files=without-match --exclude={*~,tags} --exclude-dir=.svn  . -e " . expand("<args>") . " " <bar> cwindow
map <C-l> :SearchAll <cword><CR>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
command! -nargs=1 MySearchFunction execute " grep -srnw --binary-files=without-match --exclude=*~ --exclude-dir=.svn  . -e " . expand("<args>") . " " <bar> cwindow
map <C-l> :MySearchFunction <cword><CR>
```

Might I suggest looking into ack and Ack.vim.

Comment: Close, but I have two issues: 1) After running the command, I get: E488: Trailing characters:  cwindow^M    2) This only finds the exact whole match. What would I do to find partial matches (ie: if I search for MY_GLOBAL_VAR  it should find MY_GLOBAL_VAR_1, MY_GLOBAL_VAR_2, etc). Thank you.

Comment: Adding slightly modified version of your answer to my original question via edit. +1; Accepted.

Comment: @Dogbert: the first issue may be caused if have any additional character after any of the two lines above. But I believe you should move to [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/why-ack/) as suggested, then you would have a better tool to perform the search, and [Ack.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2572) plugin which already implements the command that you wants.